# How can i make pictures resizable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am learning to design a website for my CS department as in my project.
i want to provide with a slideshow of department resources or say snapshots.
I wish to know how to make the slideshow, and how to position images in such a way that it fits all browsers widths perfectly.
Please Help !

Comment: As for the image widths, this article may help: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: If we provide an answer, and you use it, won't you be "copying it from the Internet"?

Comment: And why would you do that? There are plenty of functional cross-browser solutions for that. You will be re-inventing the wheel and it will take a lot of time to make it cool and compatible like one of theese http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/top-10-javascript-slideshows-carousels-and-sliders

Comment: Way too broad a question, and more than one question at any rate.

Comment: Please ask a specific question. To answer all of your very broad questions we need to write a book.

Comment: Also you should ask here for specific problem solution and not just "I want to write this application, how should i do it?" Thats just silly sorry :-)

Comment: @thirtydot i just wished to learn .. I have plenty of options to copy.

Comment: @Gatekeeper Yeah I may sound silly. but instead of asking many small questions. I thought to sum up all in one.

Comment: @Styrr you can just guide me brother. I will try to take whatever few lines you can teach me. thankyou.

Comment: @Rachit Mishra you know google, right? I think you should study some solutions yourself and ask only if you dont understand some specific problem and cant find answer yourself. This is what this site is for. Your question is like "hey i want to know how to write things in js, teach me!" RTFM man :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get images to fit all widths, use `width: 100%;` in your css. As the comments suggest, by asking SO you *will* be copying from the internet, so if you really don't want to do that, don't read my answer =P